# How to convert HTMLCollection to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'am working on a bot that will edit some form on website, one part of the form is  where is some html. I copy data from the  converting to HTMLCollection do some actions, and then i want to save it back to the . And in case to do so i need to convert HTMLCollection object back to a string.

How i get and convert the data:

```
var htmlFromTextArea = document.getElementById('nameOfTextArea').value;
var htmlObject = document.createElement('div');
htmlObject.innerHTML = htmlFromTextArea; 
var htmlElements = htmlObject.getElementsByTagName("*")
```

And now i need htmlElements to become string again

I tried the following but it seems not working:

```
var stringWithHtmlTobeSavedInTextArea = htmlElements.text;
```

or

```
var stringWithHtmlTobeSavedInTextArea = htmlElements.textContent;
```

or

```
var stringWithHtmlTobeSavedInTextArea = htmlElements.innerText;
```

Comment: Why not using `var stringWithHtmlTobeSavedInTextArea = htmlObject.innerHTML`??

Comment: Do you want to use jquery as well?

Comment: Since htmlObject.getElementsByTagName("*"); returns HTMLCollection having length as 0, that is the reason htmlElements.text, htmlElements.textContent, htmlElements.innerText returns undefined, because htmlObject has no child, hence you have to add child in htmlObject to make it work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `htmlElements` is [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). So seperate each element and add `outerHTML` of element to string using loop.

```js
var htmlObject = document.createElement('div');
htmlObject.innerHTML = "<a>anchor</a><p>paragraph</p>"; 
var htmlElements = htmlObject.getElementsByTagName("*");
var stringWithHtmlTobeSavedInTextArea="";
for (i = 0; i < htmlElements.length ; i++){
    stringWithHtmlTobeSavedInTextArea += htmlElements[i].outerHTML;
}
console.log(stringWithHtmlTobeSavedInTextArea);
```

Please note that, above solution is not correctly working in case if the HTML inside div element is like `<div><a>anchor</a></div>`

So It is better to use `innerHTML` or get actual text from `<textarea>` eg.

```
var stringWithHtmlTobeSavedInTextArea = htmlObject.innerHTML;
//Or 
var stringWithHtmlTobeSavedInTextArea = htmlFromTextArea;
```

Comment: innerHTML suggestion seems better)